# How to implement user-defined function (external function) in CLIPS

Tags: c, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, clips

Trying to implement an external function in CLIPS, I followed the instructions provided in the apg.pdf document (Section 3: Integrating CLIPS with External Function). By reproducing the example in paragraph 3.2.2., Two files have been created, rta.h and rta.c, containing the following instructions:

```
/* rta.h */

#ifndef _H_rta
#define _H_rta

double rta(void *environment);

#endif
```

```
/* rta.c*/

#include "rta.h" 

double rta(void *environment)
{
double base, height;
/*==================================*/
/* Check for exactly two arguments. */
/*==================================*/
if (EnvArgCountCheck(environment,"rta",EXACTLY,2) == -1) return(-1.0);
/*===============================================*/
/* Get the values for the 1st and 2nd arguments. */
/*===============================================*/
base = EnvRtnDouble(environment,1);
height = EnvRtnDouble(environment,2);
/*==================================*/
/* Return the area of the triangle. */
/*==================================*/
return(0.5 * base * height);
}
```

In userfunctions.c, rta function is declared  in EnvUserFunctions, like the code below:

```
#include "clips.h"

void UserFunctions(void);
void EnvUserFunctions(void *);

void UserFunctions()
  {
   // Use of UserFunctions is deprecated.
   // Use EnvUserFunctions instead.
  }
  
void EnvUserFunctions(
  void *environment)
  {
#if MAC_XCD
#pragma unused(environment)


/*========================================*/
/* Declare your C functions if necessary. */
/*========================================*/
extern double rta(void *);


/*=========================================================*/
/* Call DefineFunction to register user-defined functions. */
/*=========================================================*/

EnvDefineFunction2(environment,"rta",'d',PTIEF rta,"rta","22n");

#endif
}
```

After integrating these two files in the CLIPS directory, and after opening in MS Visual C ++ (MS Visual
Studio 2015) CLIPS.sln which is located in the directory:

C: \ clips_windows_projects_630 \ Projects \ CLIPS_MVS_2013

I have compiled rta.h and rta.c and run the build command for CLIPSIDE.
Once the build finished successfully, and after opening CLIPSIDE from the directory:

C: \ clips_windows_projects_630 \ Projects \ CLIPS_MVS_2013 \ Executables \ Win32 \ Release

I obtain this result:

```
                           CLIPS (6.30 3/17/15)
CLIPS> (rta 2.0 3.0)

[EXPRNPSR3] Missing function declaration for rta.
CLIPS>
```

The question is: where is the error and how to correct it in order to include an external function in CLIPS.
Thanks in advance for any help to come.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error you've described. I had to add #include "clips.h" to rta.c in order for the file to compile. Both rta.c and rta.h were added to the CLIPSIDE project and EnvUserFunctions was modified as described in your question.

Comment: As we say in French: " eh bien ça marche !"  ("it works!"). Actually, I try to implement to implement the Kruskal algorithm through external functions such as the rta function, but the concern is the use of matrices.
Anyway, thanks again Mr. Riley.